# The linear system associated to a blow-up(of surfaces)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Take a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^2_k$ and blow it up. Then we get a morphism $f:X \rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2_k$ from the blow-up. This should then be describe by a linear system on $X$. What is that linear system?

I am of the belief that the linear system is the complete linear system $|\widehat{C}+E|$ where $C$ is a line through the origin and the hat indicates we are taking the strict transform.

Is this correct? I can add more details if needed.

Comment: The right answer should just be $f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^2}(1))$, no? So this should just be a question about whether your system is equal to this one.

Comment: Yeah precisely. That’s why I chose said linear system — they’re the same. Thanks!

Comment: Oops — I got your confusion. I wrote the pullback of $K_X$ when I meant $E$.